# Need MySQL database schema for handling complex data import

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Here's what I already have:

PHP/MySQL web interface allows you to upload a csv file. The program scans the file to determine appropriate data types for each column, then writes the file into a new table in MySQL.

Then, you "map" the data, assigning different columns in the raw table (the one just imported) to the core attributes (e.g. sku, cost, color, collection_name, height, MSRP, etc).

My problem is in figuring out a good schema for storing the processes that can be taken.

Examples.

A raw file has fields: item_number, list_price, description

These would map to item_number maps to sku, list_price maps to MSRP but also to cost, description maps to color and colletion name.

For varchar type fields, I can use a translation table to lookup the "core" value to translate to.
For numeric types, like "list_price" in the raw file, I would need to store some kind of numeric conversion rules. E.g. 'list_price' = 2.0 * core_attribute_cost.

How would I go about storing and retrieving mathematical operations and their operands? Is there a simple solution that I'm missing? Because I'm currently thinking of having a math table with "x+y", "x/y","y/x", "y-x", "x-y", where x will be the input field and y will be either a saved value  (like "2.0") or another field. This seems endlessly complex.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a fixed number of variables?  Will they only ever form a linear system?  If so, you could just store the coefficient of each variable in its own column...  **EDIT** of course, you just said that there may be terms such as x/y etc, for which this solution may not be ideal.  You could store e.g. `"$x/$y"` and use PHP's [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function (provided you're *certain* the data is "safe" from user manipulation).

Comment: I think I have a working model for varchar fields. My main problem is probably that it seems impossible to store a multitude of mathematical operations relationally. Taking advantage of eval() may be an important step in simplification for the short term. Currently, the incoming data is totally safe from user manipulation, but may not be in the distant future (once I get out of alpha).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you import all the data into a single flat table with the columns that you need, and will include in the CSV file.

Once the import is done then you can run SQL queries to insert the data into your normalized database following pre-defined rules.

Therefore your import process is 2-step, but provides you with the flexibility to adjust either the CSV import file or the business rules from the flat table to your database schema without affecting the other